# Nuxt Deploy does not end Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, npm, nuxt.js, digital-ocean

I want to deploy my nuxt project with npm run build on my DigitalOcean server. However, while loading vuetify modules in the client part, it is interrupted. What can be the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlgSR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VPS lacks the resources (memory/CPU) needed to run the build— the same happens when trying to build Nuxt apps on AWS EC2 micro instances.

Your options are:

1. Upgrade your VPS.
2. Build your production app on your local machine and upload the build files to your VPS.

Comment: Thank you. I build in local machine then after nuxt start in remote server. But now i get that error. Have any idea? Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Comment: I’d recommend closing this question (accepting the answer, if it worked for you) and then posting that error message as a separate question as it’s a separate issue. I’m sure someone will be able to help :)

Comment: Thank you. I teach close question. im newest here :)